# While and if loops not able to get working

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know why but I keep getting the code ending straight after the input part.

I have tried using `elif` but i get invalid syntax.

```py
import getpass 

answer1 = getpass.getpass(prompt = "Hello Player 1, Please pick either     ROCK (1)    SCISSORS (2)   OR   PAPER (3) \n")  

answer2 = input(("Hello Player 2, Please pick either     ROCK (1)    SCISSORS (2)   OR   PAPER (3) \n")) 

Forever = 0
while Forever < 1:  
   if answer1 == 1 and answer2 == 1:  
      print('DRAW PLAY AGAIN !')  
      Forever = Forever + 1 

   if answer1 == 2 and answer2 == 2:  
      print('DRAW PLAY AGAIN !')  
      Forever = Forever + 1 

   if answer1 == 3 and answer2 == 3:  
      print('DRAW PLAY AGAIN !')  
      Forever = Forever + 1 

   if answer1 == 1 and answer2 == 2:  
      print('Player 1 wins !') 
      Forever = Forever + 1 

   if answer1 == 3 and answer2 == 1:  
      print('Player 1 wins !')  
      Forever = Forever + 1 

   if answer1 == 2 and answer2 == 3:  
      print('Player 1 wins !')  
      Forever = Forever + 1 

   if answer1 == 2 and answer2 == 1:  
      print('Player 2 wins !')  
      Forever = Forever + 1 

   if answer1 == 1 and answer2 == 3:  
      print('Player 2 wins !')  
      Forever = Forever + 1 

   if answer1 == 3 and answer2 == 2:  
      print('Player 2 wins !')  
      Forever = Forever + 1
```

The code never ends as well.

Comment: You say *the code ending straight after the input part* but then *The code never ends as well*. So which one is it? Please provide more information on what exactly goes wrong. Since this code uses `input`, give example inputs with expected VS. actual results. Does anything gets printed to the screen at all?

Comment: Also, I will take a wild guess here and assume that because you didn't do `int(input(...))`, your input is a string and you're comparing it to an int so any of the conditions ever hold, and your loop runs forever...

Comment: input() == string, you test against integer as @Tomerikoo pointed out ...

Comment: Would also like to point out that you seem to be using the `Forever` variable as a method of breaking out of the loop, you can just use `break` to do that when you've reached a condition where you want out of the loop

Comment: The code doesn't do anything after you input. Thanks for the help anyway guys

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are taking one input with `input` and one with `getpass`, but anyway you should change both to:

```py
answer1 = int(getpass.getpass(...)) 
answer2 = int(input(...))
```

All your conditions are of the form: `answer1 == 2`. The result of `input` is a string, so all those checks fail unless you convert the input to an int.

---

I would suggest also changing the conditions to make the code simpler. You could actually have just 3! Most basic suggestion: Instead of 3 different checks printing `DRAW!` you could do:

```py
if answer1 == answer2:
    print('DRAW PLAY AGAIN !')
```

---

Last note: in python, don't use an int to check the loop... Either do `while True:` and `break when` necessary, or simply use a `Boolean` variable.